# C++ Some issues with functions for a program

Tags: c++

So i am having issues with the Void printresult function.
I can't get it to work the compiler error i get is outFile is not declared and highest score "Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type. 
Some direction would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int NO_OR_STUDENTS = 20;


struct studentType
{
    string studentFName;
    string studentLName;
    int testScore;
    char grade;
};


void getData(ifstream& inFile, studentType sList[], int listSize);
void calculateGrade(studentType sList[], int listSize);
int highestScore(const studentType sList[], int listSize);
void printResult(ofstream& outFile, const studentType sList[], int listSize);


int main()
{
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;
    studentType studentList[NO_OR_STUDENTS];
    inData.open("Ch9_Ex2Data.txt");
    if(!inData)
    {
        cout << "The input file does not exist. Program terminates!"
            << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }//endif


    outData.open("Ch11_Ex1Out.txt");
    if(!outData)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the output file. Program terminates!"
            << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }//endif


    getData(inData, studentList, NO_OR_STUDENTS);
    calculateGrade(studentList, NO_OR_STUDENTS);
    printResult(outData, studentList, NO_OR_STUDENTS);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}//endmain


void getData(ifstream& inFile, studentType sList[], int listSize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        inFile >> sList[i].studentFName >> sList[i].studentLName
        >> sList[i].testScore;
}//endgetData


void calculateGrade(studentType sList[], int listSize)
{
    int score;
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    if(score >= 90)
        sList[i].testScore = 'A';
    else if(score >= 80)
        sList[i].testScore = 'B';
    else if(score >= 70)
        sList[i].testScore = 'C';
    else if(score >= 60)
        sList[i].testScore = 'D';
    else
        sList[i].testScore = 'F';

    //student writes code for this function
}//endcalculateGrade



int highestScore(const studentType sList[], int scores[], int listSize) //orignal parameters only had one array and an int
//must pass in the scores array otherwise the program has no idea what it is inside the function
{
    int highestScore = scores[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    {

        if(scores[i] > highestScore)
        {
            highestScore = scores[i];
        }

    }
}




void printResult(ofstream& outFile, const studentType sList[], int listSize)
{

    int maxScore;

    int maxScore = highestScore(sList, listSize);
    int i;
    outFile << setw(15) << "Student Name "
        << setw(10) << "Test Score"
        << setw(7) << "Grade" << endl;
    for(i = 1; i < listSize; i++)
        outFile << left << setw(25)
        << sList[i].studentLName + ", " + sList[i].studentFName
        << right << " " << setw(5) << sList[i].testScore
        << setw(6) << " " << sList[i].grade << endl;
    outFile << endl << "Highest Test Score: " << maxScore << endl;
    outFile << "Students having the highest test score:" << endl;
    for(i = 1; i < listSize; i++)
    if(sList[i].testScore == maxScore)
        outFile << sList[i].studentLName + ", " + sList[i].studentFName << endl;
}//endprintResult
```

Comment: On your next question, put a more rich title. What is the line of the error?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira On the next question?? How about improving the current one? And not just the title. Indentation. Spelling. Format. Everything.

Comment: Line 125, @jogojapan sorry to upset you so much didn't mean to make this an issue for you.

Comment: @jogojapan I was not sure the title could be changed after the question has been created. Also, haven't noticed the lack of identation at all: my eyes just skipped everything the moment I saw the size of the code. Couldn't agree more with you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a more meaningful title that has some information about your question. "C++ Program problems" is absolutely useless as a search term by future users of this site, and it gives no useful information about the problem you're having to us now.

Comment: Help #1: Get a decent editor - visual studio express is free, or notepad++ if you don't want an IDE. Help #2: When posting to Stack Overflow you need to indent your code by four spaces for it to recognize it as code. Help #3: Simplify your code down to where it works, and then build upward, gradually.

Comment: Where is my code not indented? And i am using Visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely culprits are the semicolons at the ends of your function definitions for those two functions. Change `void printResult(ofstream& outFile, const studentType sList[], int listSize);` to `void printResult(ofstream& outFile, const studentType sList[], int listSize)` and similarly for highestScore and see if that makes anything better.

EDIT: Two more problems (as found in comments): you've forgotten a closing brace in your for loop in the `highestScore()` function, and you need to `return highScore;` afterwards.

Also, you have two versions of that function declared - I'm not sure whether that's a copy-paste error or you actually have two of them in your code, but whatever it is, get rid of one of them!

Comment: That fixed the print results but now i am having an issue with the highest score expecting a { on line 2                                              int highestScore(const studentType sList[], int listSize)
    {
     int highscore = scores[0];
     for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
    
     
      if (scores[i] > highscore)
       {
       highscore = scores[i];
      }
     }
    }

Comment: welp, check the answer after mine as well ^^

Comment: It looks like you forgot to close your for loop in that function with a end brace.

Comment: Aaaaand you don't return anything from that function. Might want to `return highScore;` at the end.

Comment: Okay i edited my question above i made the changes now i have a problem line 109 int maxScore redefinition.

Comment: Because on what I am assuming is line 109 you redefine `int maxScore`. Do you even read the errors you paste into stackoverflow? The lines `int maxScore; int maxScore = highestScore(sList, listSize)` are almost guaranteed to be lines 107-109 in your code, and whatever editor you are using MUST include some sort of 'what line am I on' thing so you can figure out EXACTLY WHERE that error is coming from.

Comment: If you don't make any sort of effort at all to figure out what the error is yourself there's no reason for me to want to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your first version of `highestScore` does not end with a brace `}` properly.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to compile your code myself, I only found 2 syntax errors:

1. You've declared 'maxscore' twice in the same scope (in 'printResult()'). Remove the first declaration that you aren't initializing.
2. 'highestScore' doesn't return anything.

After fixing these your code should compile, though 'score' in 'calculateGrade()' isn't initialized so it won't be acting as you expect.

Pay attention to any warnings that are generated as well, most warnings actually end up causing bugs in your code, so fixing them will help to minimize bugs.